# how to access same session in different codeigniter project with in same server?

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

How to access same session variable in different codeigniter project within same server ? Please help me . When I set a session variable in one project , not get the value from another project .

Comment: where are u storing the session?

Comment: try storing it in db and accessing the same across projects

Answer (score 0):

Although, accessing the session variables across differnt projects is a security violation, but since you asked, you can access the session variables using databases.

In your config file

```
$config['sess_table_name']              = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_driver']              = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name']             = 'ci_session';
```

set the driver as database.

Then create your sessions table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
`id` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
`ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
`data` blob NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

This table will now be used by the codeigniter to store sessions. You can access the data(session variables) from this table, across your projects.

Please note that, codeigniter regenerates the session id every 5 mins and updates it. So, you need to keep a track of the old or parent Id in case you want to access that. Also, you can generate and keep your own ID for referencing purpose, to avoid using CI'ssession Id.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to share session between two web applications. Every web application runs within it's own process and has it's boundaries which are there for a reason.

However , 
You can do this  of using:

cookie storage (not ideal, small storage size, sensitive data in a cookie?).
database sessions (persisted using session id cookie).
Override and roll your own (to use native php sessions!)

Since you need to make sure your session identifier is configured correctly so both apps . If using the database implementation, you need to make sure both apps can access the same DB.

**Just Make sure your $config['encryption_key']** is same for both projects.

Store your session in DB, and use the same DB for both projects.

Codeiniter 2+:

```
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'ci_sessions';
```

Codeiniter 3+:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

Codeigniter 2 MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `ci_sessions` (
    session_id varchar(40) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    ip_address varchar(45) DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    user_agent varchar(120) NOT NULL,
    last_activity int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    user_data text NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (session_id),
    KEY `last_activity_idx` (`last_activity`)
);
```

Codeigniter 3 MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
    `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
    `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
    `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
    `data` blob NOT NULL,
    KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```